# Static context in an NPM module across local PM2 cluster (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I'm dealing and wondering with context issues (and possibilities) in our microservice backend and I'm trying to better understand what exactly is shared across NodeJS forked cluster instances (for example using PM2).

The situation - lets assume I have an NPM package named that exports one instance of itself as in:

```
class Content {

constructor(){
   if(!Content.Registry) Content.Registry = {};
}

registerStatic(key,obj) {
    Content.Registry[key] = obj;
}
getStatic(key){
    return Content.Registry[key];
}
}

module.exports = new Content();
```

and my Node application includes this module at several points and registers the instances of several objects using the static context methods.
Now, I know that the require registry from Node caches the instances when you require a package (or to maybe go with a better wording that suits the node documentation - it will 'probably' bring out the same cached instance).

Questions asked:

1. can I count on the package being cached? I require it as an NPM module and not as a file (require('package-name'))
2. if even though the instance returned from the require registry won't be the same - will the static context be the same across the same PID? (Content.Registry)
3. to complicate things a bit more - when running this whole thing over PM2 - will every forked child PID will have a different package instance AND static context? will the static context be preserved? I have already noticed that Node shares some resources (the sharing of sockets via IPC is documented, however we found that even file handles are shared when trying to write to the same file from different PM2 instances - logic says each one will try to acquire a lock handle on the file but only one will succeed. in reality they all write together - this was done using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston))

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: would there even be any way to test for this? could I somehow access within the NPM package some node/javascript functionality that would give me some UUID of the package's instance? memory address?